# VB Script in excel Error91

Tags: excel, vba

When I'm running a macro, it throws a Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.

```
Sheets("POC").Select
Range("A2:M3000").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With

**ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POC Journal").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear**
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POC").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("K1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POC").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: Which line in particular do you get this error on? Do you have Option Explicit turned on and have you declared (Dim) all your variables before using them?

Comment: i get it on below line ---
**ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POC Journal").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear**

Comment: i do have Dim declared

Answer (score 0):

Should it be Worksheets("POC Journal") or Worksheets("POC")?

If the name if correct it may be because the autofilter is not turned on. You can test it and turn it on with this code:

```
 If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POC Journal").AutoFilterMode = False Then
        Selection.AutoFilter
 End If
```